lerna ERR! E409 Failed to save packument

Current Behavior
After a failed first attempt at lerna publish (70% of packages got published before failure), I get this message:
lerna ERR! E409 Failed to save packument. A common cause is if you try to publish a new package before the previous package has been fully processed.
This is my release command:
"release": "lerna clean --yes && lerna bootstrap && lerna run --parallel build && lerna publish from-package"
Expected Behavior
I expect it to publish all packages successfully
It has been working just fine before now
This issue may not be prioritized if details are not provided to help us reproduce the issue.
Failure Logs / Configuration

lerna.json
{
  "packages": [
    "packages/*",
    "docs"
  ],
  "version": "independent",
  "stream": true,
  "hoist": true,
  "command": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "npmClientArgs": ["--no-package-lock"]
    },
    "publish": {
      "ignoreChanges": ["**/stories/**", "**/tests/**"]
    }
  }
}



Environment
System:
OS: macOS 14.4.1
CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1 Pro
Binaries:
Node: 16.19.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.19 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/bin/yarn
npm: 9.4.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/bin/npm
Utilities:
Git: 2.39.2 - /usr/bin/git
npmPackages:
lerna: ^6.5.1 => 6.6.2
At first I thought it was NPM registry delay, but I have waited for hours before attempting to publish again but keep getting the same error.

I see you opened an issue here https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/4016
I also see the same in our pipeline at Prisma, and since it's something happening on npm's backend I'm going to open a support issue now.
For us the first failure is:
Wed, 29 May 2024 15:57:09 GMT npm notice
Wed, 29 May 2024 15:57:09 GMT npm notice   @prisma/debug@5.15.0-dev.49
Wed, 29 May 2024 15:57:09 GMT npm notice Tarball Contents
Wed, 29 May 2024 15:57:09 GMT npm notice 11.4kB LICENSE
Wed, 29 May 2024 15:57:09 GMT npm notice 946B README.md
Wed, 29 May 2024 15:57:09 GMT npm notice 1.1kB dist/index.d.ts
Wed, 29 May 2024 15:57:09 GMT npm notice 7.6kB dist/index.js
Wed, 29 May 2024 15:57:09 GMT npm notice 123B dist/util.d.ts
Wed, 29 May 2024 15:57:09 GMT npm notice 3.2kB dist/util.js
Wed, 29 May 2024 15:57:09 GMT npm notice 933B package.json
Wed, 29 May 2024 15:57:09 GMT npm notice Tarball Details
Wed, 29 May 2024 15:57:09 GMT npm notice name: @prisma/debug
Wed, 29 May 2024 15:57:09 GMT npm notice version: 5.15.0-dev.49
Wed, 29 May 2024 15:57:09 GMT npm notice filename: prisma-debug-5.15.0-dev.49.tgz
Wed, 29 May 2024 15:57:09 GMT npm notice package size: 8.9 kB
Wed, 29 May 2024 15:57:09 GMT npm notice unpacked size: 25.2 kB
Wed, 29 May 2024 15:57:09 GMT npm notice shasum: b46f4cbb0bd566b7fa55d2c8c9a79b44f5a9a0bf
Wed, 29 May 2024 15:57:09 GMT npm notice integrity: sha512-II3P2K5mbJ+MD[...]R++UZTLWJCDnw==
Wed, 29 May 2024 15:57:09 GMT npm notice total files: 7
Wed, 29 May 2024 15:57:09 GMT npm notice
Wed, 29 May 2024 15:57:09 GMT npm notice Publishing to https://registry.npmjs.org/ with tag dev and public access
Wed, 29 May 2024 15:57:10 GMT npm notice publish Signed provenance statement with source and build information from GitHub Actions
Wed, 29 May 2024 15:57:10 GMT npm notice publish Provenance statement published to transparency log: https://search.sigstore.dev/?logIndex=97910083
Wed, 29 May 2024 15:57:32 GMT npm error code E409
Wed, 29 May 2024 15:57:32 GMT npm error 409 Conflict - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/@prisma%2fdebug - Failed to save packument. A common cause is if you try to publish a new package before the previous package has been fully processed.

https://github.com/prisma/prisma/actions/runs/9289279373/job/25562781978#step:5:474
And fails continuously since, see https://github.com/prisma/prisma/actions/workflows/release-ci.yml

It turns out that this issue was coming from the NPM registry. I was able to publish all packages after about 18 hours.
Github link where you can follow the issue
